# Set height of an ImageView equal beside element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` and `EditText`.
i want to set my `ImageView` height equal to `EditText`
Set height of `EditText` `wrap_conten` but i don't know how to set the ImageView height !
is there anyway to do it with xml ?
Its the layout of my elements :

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
  android:layout_width="48dp"
  android:layout_height="48dp"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:background="@drawable/selector_conversation_sent"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_action_sticker"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:contentDescription=""/>

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edtContent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgSticker"
  android:maxHeight="75dip"
  android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
  android:hint="@string/compose_content"
  android:paddingTop="16dp"
  android:autoText="true"/>
```

Comment: You can use android:leftDrawable on EditText. May be that would help you better. You can also programmatically calculate the height of EditText and can set same height to your ImageView.

Comment: drawableLeft or leftDrawable ? what is it exactly ? i dont want to do it programmatically till i couldnt find any non programmatically way

Comment: It's drawableLeft on EditText in xml file. You can have alook http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: it seems it doesnt good for me :/ i dont want to remove image viw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:hint="compose_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"  //drawble image
    android:drawablePadding="10dp" // padding
    android:maxHeight="75dip"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

if u have any events for ur image then u should take separate `imageview`

using linear layout weight property u can solve ur issue

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="#ff0000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:hint="compose_content"
        android:maxHeight="75dip"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: good but the problem is i need the imageview ! i handle its onclick to open a dialog , then i dont want to remove it

Comment: why  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` ? height of my image is less than editText

Comment: weight property will take care of that...and it will help u to design compatibility too..

Comment: i do it by change the height of image to fill parent and height of linear layout with wrap-content and its done ! any way thank you :) i will accept your answer ;-)